# JavaScript regex (missing '/'), how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have simple script, I want to get my images and then divide them by commas. However I cannot get image links inside `[gallery]` tags since I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /`.

Can someone please take a look and show me where is the problem in my RegEx code?

**HTML**

```
<textarea>
abc
[gallery]/content/img/upload/img-2012.03.19.-634677727044317051.jpg, /content/img/upload/img-2012.03.19.-634677727046997204.jpg, /content/img/upload/img-2012.03.19.-634677727049487347.jpg, /content/img/upload/img-2012.03.19.-634677727051787478.jpg, /content/img/upload/img-2012.03.19.-634677727054137613.jpg[/gallery]
def
</textarea>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
    var text = $('textarea').val();
    var re = /\[gallery\]([^}]+)[/gallery\]/g;
    var gallery = re.exec(text);
    alert(gallery);
});​
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/BcFsg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the updated fiddle... I do not know why but it seems you do not have to escape the closing `]`

EDIT: gave wrong output (all squared brackets need to be escaped)...  updated fiddle
EDIT 2: updated fiddle to only alert the list of images

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcFsg/4/)

Comment: Hm, how can I make it spit out group 1 instead of 0 (I mean spit out what's inside of `[gallery]` tags, without tags themselves?)

Comment: Please add relevant code to the answer so people do not have to go the external link.

Answer (score 2):

yep, the problem is you missed one escape character

```
var re = /\[gallery\]([^}]+)\[\/gallery\]/g;
//                          |
//                       [ HERE ]
```

jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/BcFsg/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `/` in the middle of the regex by eriting `\/`.